# Architecture for processing asyncronous HTTP request/response : ESB vs Async Http Client library

Tags: java, web-services, apache-camel, esb, apache-servicemix

We are developing an application integrator which sends requests to various webservices simultaneously, aggregate data return by each webservice and format it to display on UI. Each webservice may have proprietary xml format. Also we don't wont to compromise user experience.

We identified ESB(Servicemix/Mule) and  Async Http Client for this requirement.

Can anyone suggest which would be better option?  Async Http Client seems good fit as it is lightweight over servicemix.

Thanks,
Amit Patel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also just use [Apache Came](http://camel.apache.org)l for this...

It supports a wide range of [components](http://camel.apache.org/components.html) and [messaging patterns](http://camel.apache.org/enterprise-integration-patterns.html), is lightweight and has a flexible deployment model (standalone, spring, maven, webapp, OSGi, etc).

Comment: Apache Camel is the winner finally.

Answer (score 0):

You have answered your own. Yes ESB is good option. You can use [**Mule**](http://www.mulesoft.org/).

Second option is Asynchronous messaging but it will be complicated, because You have to orchestrate the services properly.

Comment: We are also looking ServiceMix. Here is the comparison between Mule and ServiceMix [link](http://servicemix.apache.org/how-does-servicemix-compare-to-mule.html)

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement, I would suggest you to go with WSO2 ESB. Its and 100% free and open source ESB (Apache License 2) and unlike other ESBs, with wso2 you don't have the commercial and community versions. So, what you [download for free](http://wso2.org/downloads/esb) from WSO2, comprises of all the features that are available in 'commercial versions' of other ESB vendors. Also, WSO2 offers not just an ESB but a complete SOA Platform for your SOA needs.

For the requirement you mentioned above, there is a [simple sample](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2011/01/wso2-esb-by-example-service-chaining) that you can try out.

Answer (score 0):

eh, we did a productivity test on coding pure java vs. ESB (mule and spring integration).  We had 3 developers do the same thing in all 3 versions (mule, SI, and just pure java with no ESB).  They finsihed 6 times faster when not using an ESB and we gave alot of things in the problem that would leverage the ESB, but in the end it did not help....all the xml coding and confusion of the api usages led to really unproductive development teams.  Not only that, it is hard to find ESB developers on the market as well.

NOTE: We even took an advanced spring integration guy that had been doing it and he also was faster in pure java to complete the code.  He loved spring integration and after taking my test, he changed his mind.

ie. be warned of the huge productivity loss that using the wrong framework can cause.  6 times is a huge penalty.  I mean 1 month vs. 6 months is a big difference.

A 6 times productivity loss is worth taking one week out and doing your own developer productivity test.  Some argued with me that they didn't know the framework yet which is why we got an advanced spring integration guy to take the test.

Also, make sure your test takes at least an hour or so....just develop some fake but realistic requirements from the application that you are going to write anyways so you make progress on your application while running the study.  I would be interested to see more results posted as well.

Comment: we did try it as it had a java api which seemed kind of nice.  We did not however run a productivity test with that specific solution but I would be interested in any results if someone does run a test.